# Argument of type 'Events' is not assignable to parameter of type

Tags: typescript

```
interface Test {
    on(event: 'a', listener: (stats: string) => void)
    on(event: 'b' | 'c', listener: (stats: string) => void)
}

const test: Test = {
    on(event, listener) {}
}

type Events = 'a' | 'b' | 'c'
const arr: Events[] = ['a', 'b', 'c']
arr.forEach(e => {
    test.on(e, () => { })
})
```

code like this in typescript, when I try to bind events to test object, it will fire error which message like this:

**Argument of type 'Events' is not assignable to parameter of type '"b" | "c"'.
  Type '"a"' is not assignable to type '"b" | "c"'.**

what should I do to avoid this kind error?

Comment: Where is `Events` interface?. You are trying to assign `string` to type `Events`

Comment: I just defined `type Events`, isn't that enough? I'm new to typescript so I guess `const arr: Events[]` means every item in arr should be Events type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e` is an `'a' | 'b' | 'c'`, not an `'a'`, not a `'b' | 'c'`. Although each value will be compatible with one of the overloads, the *type* is not.

You can fix this by allowing the full type (you don't need any overloads if you do this as it handles all three cases):

```
on(event: 'a' | 'b' | 'c', listener: (stats: string) => void)
```

Or by narrowing the type before you call the `on` method:

```
type Events = 'a' | 'b' | 'c'
const arr: Events[] = ['a', 'b', 'c']
arr.forEach(e => {
    if (e === 'a') {
        test.on(e, () => { })
    } else {
        test.on(e, () => { })
    }
})
```

Comment: It seems fixed by narrowing the type before call the `on` method, but is there any way to fix this by define Events?

Comment: @jokcylou - I don't know if it is possible in your case, but the following would work: `on(event: Events, listener: (stats: string) => void)`. It means changing the interface, rather than events, but it keeps them joined up.

Comment: yeah it will work. but in my real world case the event is defined by a third part pkg -- which is webpack-serve. so I don't have that chance to change the interface. anyway I have got the reason. thx for your answer, and sorry for my poor english

Comment: @jokcylou - your English was spot on.